# How to access a MySQL database on windows server machine from another windows server machine

Tags: mysql, database, windows, server

I ran this command:-

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

on the windows server machine which contains the mysql database but I'm unable to access it using a PHP app on another windows machine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the connection request from your php program failing? What error message to you receive?

Answer (score 0):

I've allowed the connection through the 3306 port from the inbound roles from windows firewall settings.